# How to deal with this firebase auth dilemma

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Given that some user userA, signed up to an application with phone number 01234.

Fast forward a month from now, userA changed phone number to 043210 but didn't change or update firebase account with new number 043210.

That means the userA account with number 01234 is still active.

Someone else userB now owns this phone number, installs given application and attempts to signup/signin with phone number 01234....

Won't this user, userB the new owner of the phone number 01234 be taken/authenticated to someone else's(userA) account? Thereby exposing userA account info/data to userB.

How does firebase deal with such a case? / How can one deal with such a case?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase documentation explicitly mentions this risk in the section on [security concerns](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#security-concerns). From there:

> Authentication using only a phone number, while convenient, is less secure than the other available methods, because possession of a phone number can be easily transferred between users. Also, on devices with multiple user profiles, any user that can receive SMS messages can sign in to an account using the device's phone number.

> If you use phone number based sign-in in your app, **you should offer it alongside more secure sign-in methods, and inform users of the security tradeoffs of using phone number sign-in.**

Comment: I missed that part. Thank you.